# Will the two lines intersect in a Cartesian plane

Tags: java, math, floating-point

I have this problem from the book 'Crack the Coding Interview'.

> Given two lines on a Cartesian plane, determine whether the two lines would intersect.`

Here is the solution:

```
public class Line {

    static double epsilon = 0.000001;
    public double slope;
    public double yintercept;

    public Line(double s, double y) {
        slope = s;
        yintercept = y;
    }

    public boolean intersect(Line line2) {
        return Math.abs(slope - line2.slope) > epsilon ||
        Math.abs(yintercept - line2.yintercept) < epsilon;
    }
}
```

Why doesnt it have the simple solution that if the slopes are not same, then they will intersect. Why the epsilon and the y intercept.

In the Suggestions it says that

> Don’t assume that the slope and y-intercept are integers. Understand limitations of floating point representations. Never check for equality with `==`.

Comment: Do you understand the problem of testing two floating-point numbers for equality?

Comment: @Beta i could use some help there too. Thanks

Comment: This is exactly why I hate floating-point data types in most cases. If I was to read that question, I'd assume that the slope and intercept are actual numbers, not floating-point representations. There's a `BigDecimal` type in java which doesn't have the floating point problem - I'm sure it's significantly slower than `double` to run calculations, but at least you wouldn't have the epsilon nonsense to deal with.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The “solution” is wrong.

Implicit in this “solution” is a notion that the arguments that have been passed are inaccurate, that, before `intersect` is called, the values have been subject to computations that may produce results with rounding errors. Because there are errors in the values, numbers that would be equal if calculated exactly are unequal. To recognize these as equal, this “solution” accepts as equal some values that are actually unequal.

One flaw in this reasoning is that the `intersect` routine has no knowledge of how large the errors may be and therefore has no basis for knowing what value of `epsilon` it should use. The ideal value might be zero, or it might be a million. The value that is used, 1e-5, has no basis in any engineering principle given the information provided. More than that, there is no basis for using an absolute error, as this code does. Depending on circumstances, the proper tolerance to use might be a relative error, an error denominated in ULPs, or some other technique. There is simply no reason to believe that this code will return `true` when passed arguments that ideally would represent intersecting lines but that have been calculated in some unknown way.

Another flaw is that the routine falsely accepts as equal values that are not equal. The routine will report as not intersecting many lines that do intersect. This code has not solved the problem of the routine returning the wrong answer; it has only changed the cases for which wrong answers are returned, and it may well have greatly increased the number of wrong answers.

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard: What specifically is your question about vertical lines?

Comment: How would the supposed solution deal with them?  Can they be represented meaningfully with this interface, and would the code give the correct answer?

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard: My answer asserts the “solution” in the question is wrong. This does not change for vertical or near-vertical lines. Two intersecting lines could be reported by `intersect` as non-intersecting because errors have made their calculated slopes equal before they are passed to `intersect` (and the calculated values might both be infinity). Similarly, two non-intersecting lines could be reported as intersecting because their ideally equal slopes have been calculated as unequal, by an amount larger than `epsilon` (especially if one is infinite and one is finite).

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard: The one possibility that vanishes for vertical or near-vertical lines is for `intercept` to accept their slopes as equal when the actual values passed are not equal. This is because the slopes will be infinite or very large, so their difference will not be less than `epsilon`.

Answer (score 5):

First because the simple solution that if the slopes are not the same they will intersect is not complete. They could have the same slope and intercept and would therefore be identical.

The epsilon as the suggestion says is because the number representation in computers is not exact. According to the [IEEE-standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) a double has about 15 precise calculated digits therefore slope and intercept can have a rounding error due to previous calculations and therefore a simple check with == could yield that they are not identical while they just differ by a rounding error.

Answer (score 4):

> Why doesnt it have the simple solution that if the slopes are not
>   same, then they will intersect. Why the epsilon and the y intercept.

The solution takes in consideration the approximation errors due to [floating-point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) arithmetic. 
Because of floating point numbers doesn't represent all possible real numbers, but a relative small subset (more dense in [-1,+1] interval), it's common when you have to deal with floating points arithmetic use a threshold to perform equality checks.

The epsilon valure represent a threshold under which 2 different floating-point values would be considered equals.

Comment: Beat us to the punch... as a student (@Kraken), you will eventually learn the differences between how a floating point number and how an integer type number are stored and operated upon, but the main thing to remember is that 20.0 - 7.0 may not be equal (using ==) to 120.0 - 117.0, for instance.

Comment: @LJ2 I guess you mean, 20.0-7.0 != to 120.0 - `107.0`?

Comment: Yes, the maths, I am not so good at them, especially when dealing with one-to-two digit subtraction :/  Thanks

Comment: @LJ2: 20. - 7. equals 120. - 107. in every common floating-point implementation. Floating-point errors do not just occur randomly; the behavior is specified, and you can rely on the behavior if you understand the specification.

Comment: @Eric: I meant my example to be hypothetical... I guess I would revise my comment to read - 'One arbitrary calculation that you would expect to have an answer precise to 15 decimal places is not necessarily equal to a different arbitrary calculation with the (EDIT: expected) same answer precise to 15 decimal places.'  Sorry for any confusion that my specific arbitrary example may have caused :)

Answer (score 1):

Underneath it all, numbers are all converted to binary when they are processed. It is not possible to represent most floating point numbers as an exact binary (because they would be an infinite series of 1s and 0s), and so approximations are made, by truncating the binary sequence. For example, the floating point number 0.1 (ie: one tenth) is not representable as an exact binary number, rather, it is represented by an approximation which looks like 0.000110011... Truncation of this binary number causes potential rounding errors, and so the exact equality "==" could cause a false response, when in fact it is this rounding error which is giving the fake negative. Introducing an epsilon attempts to avoid these errors by saying "anything below this number we consider to be zero". See the "fractions in binary" section of [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_numeral_system) to read more.

Comment: As usual this only moves the problem to the choice of the value of epsilon, which is not easy decidable.